# i want to make accordion which one 1st element of accordion will open by default

Tags: javascript

I want to make accordion which one is 1st panel will open by default and when the user clicks other panels of an element the 1st panel will automatically close and other is usually open.
note: I want to make it with pure javascript without any help of any single framework.

```
<div id="accordion">
        <div class="panel">
            <!-- first panel -->
            <div class="header">header1</div>
            <div class="body">body of panel 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <!-- second panel -->
            <div class="header">header2</div>
            <div class="body">body of panel 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <!-- third panel -->
            <div class="header">header3</div>
            <div class="body">body of panel 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Add code, we can't help you without it!

Comment: here is the html code

Answer (score 0):

This might give you an idea, the idea is simply check for the hover and add a class,in the case it exits the container, it should add the class back to the first element

```js
function addClass(elem){
  panels.map(panel => panel.classList.remove('active'))
  elem.classList.add('active');
}
function removeClass(){
  this.classList.remove('active');
}


const panels = [...document.querySelectorAll('.panel')];
const container = document.querySelector('#accordion');

panels.map(panel => {
  panel.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=>addClass(panel));
  panel.addEventListener('mouseleave', removeClass);
})

container.addEventListener('mouseleave', ()=>addClass(panels[0]));
```

```css
#accordion {
  display: flex;
}
.panel {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.panel .body {
  display: none;
}
.panel.active .body {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="accordion">
        <div class="panel active">
            <!-- first panel -->
            <div class="header">header1</div>
            <div class="body">body of panel 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <!-- second panel -->
            <div class="header">header2</div>
            <div class="body">body of panel 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <!-- third panel -->
            <div class="header">header3</div>
            <div class="body">body of panel 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```